# Magento 2 get image for Subcategory Collection

Tags: magento2, category, image

I'm trying to get image for category in magento 2

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,

public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    return $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
}

public function getCurrentChildCategories()
{
    $categories = $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
    return $categories;
}

public function getCurrentChildSubCategories($cat)
{
    $subcategories = $cat->getChildrenCategories();
    return $subcategories;
}
```

and phtml:

```
<?php $_categories = $block->getCurrentChildCategories(); ?>
<?php
foreach ($_categories as $category):
    echo ("</br>".$category->getName());
    $_subcategories = $block->getCurrentChildSubCategories($category);
    foreach ($_subcategories as $subcategory):
        echo ("</br>_".$subcategory->getName());
    endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

but there are no image href column name in category collection. How can I get image in category collection or how can i get image by entity_id in magento 2 correctly? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should add an event in etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before">
        <observer name="add_image_to_collection" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\AddImage" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and the observer:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddImage implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $select = $observer->getSelect();
        return $select->columns('image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which observer? And does that frontend/events.xml go in the themes etc folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your block code should be:

```
<?php

namespace Module\Name\Block;

class CategoriesCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_categoryHelper;
     protected $categoryFlatConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */   
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }

   public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
           if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
                $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            } else {
                $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
            }
            return $subcategories;
    }
}
?>
```

Your template code should be:

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
$_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<div class="block widget block-products-list grid">
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="products-grid grid">
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
<?php 
if (!$category->getIsActive()) { 
        continue;
     }
$subcats = $this->getChildCategories($category);
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
            <ol class="product-items widget-product-grid">
                <?php
                foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                    if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                        $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                        $subcaturl = $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($subcat);

                        $_imgHtml = '';
                        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {

                            $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                            $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');

                            /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo '<li class="product-item"><div class="product-item-info"><a href="' . $subcaturl . '" class="product-item-photo" title="' . $subcat->getName() . '"><span class="product-image-container"><span class="product-image-wrapper">' . $_imgHtml . '</span></span></a></div></li>';
                        }

                    }
                } ?>
            </ol>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to rip off someone else's bad answer then you should at least give them credit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/getting-sub-category-images-in-magento2