# Getting Sub Category Images in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, image

I am trying to get at Category Images from within `Magento_Catalog\template\navigation\left.phtml`.  This file shows a list of sub-categories.

This is that file:

```
<?php if (!$block->getCategory()) {
    return;
} ?>
<?php $_categories = $block->getCurrentChildCategories(); ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories) ? count($_categories) : $_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if ($_count): ?>
    <div class="block filter">
        <div class="title">
            <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shop By') ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <strong class="subtitle"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
            <dl class="options" id="narrow-by-list2">
                <dt><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Category') ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ol class="items">
                        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                            <?php if ($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                                <li class="item">
                                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($block->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $block->getCategory($_category)->getImageUrl(); ?>">
                                        <p><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></p>
                                    </a>
                                    <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_category->getProductCount() ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ol>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The line I was hoping would work is:

```
$block->getCategory($_category)->getImageUrl();
```

However this is returning the image for the current category, not the sub-categories.

Answer (score 11):

[Three hours later...](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wuzyX1YiUYk/maxresdefault.jpg)

This will render from a category page. You may have to modify to work with your exact requirements.

Add this block to your Module: `Block/CategoryCollect.php`

```
<?php
namespace Joshua34\UpdateHead\Block;
class CategoryCollect extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $categoryFlatConfig;
    protected $topMenu;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Return categories helper
     * getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
     * example getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', 0)
     */
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->topMenu->getHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current store categories
     *
     * @param bool|string $sorted
     * @param bool $asCollection
     * @param bool $toLoad
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
     */
    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child store categories
     *
     */
    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
        if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
            $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        } else {
            $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
        }
        return $subcategories;
    }
}
```

Add this template file to your Module: `view/frontend/templates/categorycollect.phtml`

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$subcats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
        if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
            $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
            $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
            $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();

            $_imgHtml = '';
            if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {

                $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');

                /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo '<li><a href="' . $subcaturl . '" class="block-promo" title="' . $subcat->getName() . '">' . $_imgHtml . '<span style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)" class="content bg-white"><strong>Place custom code here</strong><br><br><span class="action more button">Learn More</span></span></a></li>';
            }
        }
    } ?>
</ul>
```

Reference from within CMS block / page

```
 {{block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\CategoryCollect" template="Vendor_ModuleName::categorycollect.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Even though I assume that would work, loading the entire category is not very efficient in terms of performance and the use of collection with `addAttributeToSelect('image')` should be preferred

Comment: Between me and M2, efficiency is constantly being sacrificed just to accomplish basic tasks. Not enough time, docs or support to discover the "best way" while still accomplishing "a way", in a timely manner.

Comment: @Joshua34com thanks for this! just want to check - is `view/frontend/templatescategorycollect.phtml` correct? I have no files there - most of my phtml files are in `Magento_Theme/templates` - if that place is correct, how do I reference it so it appears on a page of my choice?

Comment: Sorry, corrected answer spelling. 
File should be created within your module here: app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/categorycollect.phtml

Comment: Reference from within CMS block / page like so: {{block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\CategoryCollect" template="Vendor_ModuleName::categorycollect.phtml"}}

Comment: I am sorry, I feel like you have invested a lot of time getting this solution - but I cannot get it to work - I keep getting this error message: `We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.` which doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Did you run the command to compile after updating your module? setup:di:compile

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism how would you get the collection there?

Answer (score 5):

You can add attributes to child category collections with a plugin, here's an example module (code not tested):

`./composer.json`

```json
{
    "name": "stackoverflow/module-child-category-image",
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "101.*",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "StackOverflow\\ChildCategoryImage\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

`./registration.php`

```php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackOverflow_ChildCategoryImage',
    __DIR__
);
```

`./etc/module.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackOverflow_ChildCategoryImage" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`./etc/di.xml`

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category">
        <plugin name="category" type="\StackOverflow\ChildCategoryImage\Plugin\Category" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`./etc/frontend/events.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before">
        <observer name="category_flat_add_image" instance="StackOverflow\ChildCategoryImage\Observer\FlatCategory" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`./Plugin/Category.php`

```php
<?php
namespace StackOverflow\ChildCategoryImage\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category as Subject;

class Category
{
    /**
     * Add Image to Child Category Collection
     *
     * @param Subject $subject
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     */
    public function afterGetChildrenCategories(
        Subject $subject,
        $collection
    ) {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('image_url');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

`./Observer/FlatCategory.php`

```php
<?php
namespace StackOverflow\ChildCategoryImage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class FlatCategory implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(
        Observer $observer
    ) {
        $select = $observer->getData('select');
        $select->columns('image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Best solution, however for Magento 2.3.3 I had to change 'image_url' to 'image' in the observer

Answer (score 3):

Lots of solutions above would cause serious performance issues. Try this.

```
$_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$_subCategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories()->addAttributeToSelect('image');
<?php foreach ($_subCategories as $_sub):?>
    <?php echo($_sub->getImageUrl());?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: be aware this will not work with "flat" categories enabled

Comment: In the interest of self improvement, where do you see a performance issue in my solution? It's just modifying the original collection with a plugin and modifying the column selection for flat?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution. I was referring to the very first solution. "            $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());" loading in the template is slow as.

Answer (score 2):

To me:

```
$block->getCategory($_category)->getImageUrl();
```

Means that you are retrieving the main category of the block so yeah to fix that, I reckon you should modify your code to this:

```
$_category->getImageUrl();
```

Comment: I agree with your first point, however `$_category->getImageUrl();` only returns false.  When I do a `var_dump(get_class_methods($_category));` there doesnt seem to be anything there that relates to images.

Comment: yeah problem is the image is not part of the child categories attribute that's why you get nothing I reckon you'll have to modify the collection to select the image

Comment: How can I modify the collection?