# Magento 2.2. - Show subcategories on category page

Tags: category, magento2.2, static-block

After searching online, I found [this approach](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110013/65994) to my problem of showing subcategories inside the category page. The above solution states to create a custom module, and then reference it with a `cms-code`.

So I created a `static block` with the reference `cms-code` inside it, and I added the `block` in a category, using the dropdown menu.

The module seems to work (I inspected the page and I can see there are `<ul></ul>` html tags), but no list of subcategories is visible.

What am i missing?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have flat categories enabled in the backend?

Comment: @Bram No I haven't, but I am thinking of enabling them. Why?

Comment: Well, I've tried to achieve the same a while back but this did not work while using flat categories. But you don't have that enabled, otherwise that maybe could've been the cause.

Comment: Did you find a solution with flat categories?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I did not. Topics opened by other users on stack could not help me